# Network packet sniffing in .NET Permission Exception

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, ip

I have a book called Network Programming in .NET which has the following code sample for sniffing IP packets on the network stack. I have copied the code sample WORD-FOR-WORD from the book so please excuse the lack of stylistic conventions etc.

```
List<string> packets = new List<string>();

public void Run()
{
    int len_receive_buf = 4096;
    int len_send_buf = 4096;
    byte[] receive_buf = new byte[len_receive_buf];
    byte[] send_buf = new byte[len_send_buf];
    int cout_receive_bytes;
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
    socket.Blocking = false;
    IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IPHost.AddressList[0].ToString()), 0));
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, 1);
    byte[] IN = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
    byte[] OUT = new byte[4];
    int SIO_RCVALL = unchecked((int)0x98000001);
    int ret_code = socket.IOControl(SIO_RCVALL, IN, OUT);
    while(true)
    {
        IAsyncResult ar = socket.BeginReceive(receive_buf, 0, len_receive_buf, SocketFlags.None, null, this);
        cout_receive_bytes = socket.EndReceive(ar);
        Receive(receive_buf, cout_receive_bytes);
    }
}

public void Receive(byte[] buf, int len)
{
    if(buf[9] == 6)
    {
        packets.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf).Replace("\0", " "));
    }
}
```

The first time I tested this was a few years ago (before even Vista existed) and the machine I used was a 32bit Windows XP Proferssional platform with a NIC running on IPv4.

I am now trying to test on a 64bit Windows 7 platform with a NIC running IPv6 but its not working. I am assuming this is something to do with IPv6. Can anyone suggest how I might fix this efficiently?

EDIT: This is the exception I get when I try to run...

[image]

Comment: I'd seriously question the authorship of any code which includes a gem like `IPAddress.Parse(IPHost.AddressList[0].ToString())` - Um, why not just `IPHost.AddressList[0]`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I quite agree!

Comment: @MartinLiversage...see my last edit.

Comment: For the exception, as the tip hints, you need to access the `ErrorCode` property to get a better steer on the issue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever for some reason, even clicking that link does not work :-/

Comment: If you click on "View Detail...", you should be able to dig into the exception object. I've updated my answer with a guess that you'll find that it is WSEACCESS (10013).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Headers are significantly different between [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) and [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet).

So the check of:

```
if(buf[9] == 6)
```

Which checks whether the packet is TCP for IPv4 is querying part of the source address field of an IPv6 packet. For IPv6, it ought to be checking "Next Header" which is at offset 6*. Of course, now you'll also have to check the IP version first to know whether to check offset 6 or offset 9.

---

For the exception message, it's likely that you're not running as Administrator, which you need to be to listen on [raw sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (native documentation, but still applicable):

> To use a socket of type **SOCK_RAW** requires administrative privileges. Users running Winsock applications that use raw sockets must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer, otherwise raw socket calls will fail with an error code of [`WSAEACCES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEACCES). On Windows Vista and later, access for raw sockets is enforced at socket creation. In earlier versions of Windows, access for raw sockets is enforced during other socket operations.

---

(*) Of course, there may be multiple IPv6 headers to work through before you discover that it's a TCP packet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting. The code clearly needs updating A LOT...see my last edit for an example exception.

Comment: Thanks for your last edit. When I run with elevated privileges it works (given a correct IP address). - Answer accepted